# Solve of the differential equation $y'=-\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}+1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've tried to solve this equation, and in the course of solving any problems. Please help me understand.
$$y'=-\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}+1$$
Results in a normal form.
$$y'=-\frac{1}{\frac{y}{x}}+\frac{y}{x}+1$$
Make replacement.
$$\frac{y}{x}=U$$
$$y'=U'x+U$$
Substitute into the original equation.
$$U'x+U=-\frac{1}{U}+U+1$$
$$\frac{dU}{dx} \cdot x = -\frac{1}{U}+1$$

What to do with it?

Comment: Your last equation is separable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Sonnhard's hint, on the left hand side you have $$\Big(1+\frac{1}{u-1}\Big)du$$
Integrate this gives you $u+\text{ln}|u-1|+C$, where $C$ is some arbitrary constant.

Comment: If u cannot be expressed as a function of x, then you have an implicit relation for the solution and that's it.

Comment: I did not understand you, show an example, please.

Comment: In this case, you have $u-1=Ae^{x-u}$ or equivalently $e^u(u-1)=Ae^x$, where $A$ is some arbitrary constant. Substitute your initial condition to obtain A, then this would be an example of an implicit relationship of the solution. You could substitute $u=y/x$ (your original substitution), then try and simplify it if you can, otherwise that would be an acceptable answer to me :)

Comment: I just edit my comment, press enter too fast sorry !

Comment: $$e^u\left(u-1\right)=e^x-C$$ 
We get this?

Comment: Yes, I merely denote $e^{-C}$ as a new arbitrary constant $A$ (according to what you get from your comment in Sonnhard's post above). It doesn't affect anything as they are just constant you can call them whatever you want because they will be uniquely determined by the initial condition.

Comment: Yes, I know that the constant ($C$) can be set as you wish. What further express $U$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24027/discussion-between-chee-han-and-andre1).

Answer (score 3):

HINT: we have
$$\frac{du}{1-\frac{1}{u}}=\frac{dx}{x}$$
the term $$\frac{u}{u-1}=\frac{u-1+1}{u-1}=1+\frac{1}{u-1}$$

Comment: Well, I'll get this equation:
$$u+\text{ln}|u-1|+C=x$$
As further express $U$ ?

Comment: plug $u=y/x$ in your equation

Comment: I understand that, but how to do it, if $U$ can not be expressed!

Comment: We did find it, then to substitute into the expression.